# Verify solution $dy/dx $ problem

Tags: calculus

I am not sure where to start with this one if i could get some direction that would be super!

I am asked to verify that $$y=\sin2x+2\cos2x $$ is the solution to $$\frac {dy}{dx}+4y=10\cos2x $$

Thank you

Comment: in your question please include how you tried to solve it so that others can help you more and point out your mistakes.

Comment: Well ... do it.  What is is the derivative of y?  What is 4 times y?  What do you get when you add the deriviative of y plus 4y together?  What do you not understand?

Comment: do you know how to find what dy/dx is?  Ignore the second equation for now, work out what dy/dx is from the first equation

Comment: Okay so $$dy/dx =2cos (2x)- 4sin (2x) $$

Comment: you are well on the way there - all you need to do is plug the RHS of dy/dx and the RHS of y = ....  into the LHS of  second equation, then do some algebra, it should then reduce to the RHS of equation 2

Comment: Awsome!  I understand now!  Thankyou so much for your help

Answer (score 3):

Starting with $y=\sin(2x)+2\cos(2x)$, compute its derivative:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=2\cos(2x)-4\sin(2x).
$$
Then, substituting into the second equation:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}+4y=2\cos(2x)-4\sin(2x)+4(\sin(2x)+2\cos(2x))=10\cos(2x).
$$